# Blender scene has no material color in three.js with ObjectLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm trying to load the scene from Blender, using ObjectLoader. The scene is loaded, but with no material colors.

Here are my blender exporter settings:

[image: blender exporter settings]

JSON: https://jsonblob.com/9e58bd8a-46ff-11e7-ae4c-0f21997a0996

And this is how I add the model to three.js scene:

```
const objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

objectLoader.load('/static/models/lighthouse.json', (group) => {
  scene.add(group);
});
```

I might have missed something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest debugging `ObjectLoader.parse`. Put a breakpoint on the line where `materials` is assigned, and ensure it actually contains data when `parseMaterials` returns. If it doesn't, open your JSON file and ensure it actually created a `materials` section (it would be a root-level object, like `json.geometries`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found decision. It was in cycles blender engine. Once I replaced it with blender render engine, I got material colors in three.js scene.

I'm not sure this is the right decision and whether the issue was exactly in blender engine, but changing the engine to blender render solved my problem.